Which artist or movement always drew their subjects in full sideways view?
I have a vague memory from art history class of an artist or abstract art movement that had all of the subjects facing sideways. Is this something that actually existed, and, if so, who were they and/or what is the art style called?
I don't remember the specific era, but this would be sometime in relatively recent history (say 1000 CE or later)

Do you remember a century? Culture? Any research that has foreclosed any options?  The trivial answer seems to be "Egyptian", but I'm not sure if that  is what you're looking for.

Without more information, I think MCW is right that this will be tough to answer. You might consider looking through the Wikipedia page on Perspective to see if it contains a name or story that rings a bell.

I believe - but could not say with 100% certainty - that Mesoamerican painting always has the subjects facing sideways as well. All instances I have been able to find of a face looking towards the viewer have been sculpted in relief - and I didn't see any with a 3/4 view or facing away from the viewer at all.
As for art styles or individual painters - none come to mind.

The ancient Egyptians usually painted people in profile.  Also, Piero della Francesca often painted portraits in profile, apparently it was the fashion in the mid-fifteenth century:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diptych_of_Federico_da_Montefeltro_and_Battista_Sforza  although his religious paintings didn't stick to that convention.

I will not post the answer since AI generated answers are discouraged here, but I posted the exact phrasing of your question into ChatGPT and it gave me a couple of C20th art styles which may fit the bill.
